# Jquery targeting an element

Tags: jquery, target

Assume the following situation

```
<div>
 <div1>

   <divA>
   </divA>

  <divB>
  </divB>

 </div1>

 <div2>
 </div2>

</div>
```

I would like to target `<div1>`, make an `addClass()` on it without adding a class to its child.

I tried to use `:nth-child(1)` selector, or `:eq()` (I am using Jquery)
. But the `:nth-child(1)` adds the class to all the 1-children element and `:eq()` doesn't fit because I want toi target `<div1>` from its parent element.

Could anyone help ?

Best,
Newben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A truely cross browser version too:

```
$('div').children('div1').addClass('la');
```

And if these divs don't have classes:

```
$('div').children().each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('la');
    break;
});
```

Comment: I don't think he really has a tag called `<div1>`, I think that's just for illustration of which `<div>` he wants to add the class to.

Comment: @mVChr vague questions r us, he should of made clear whether or not these divs had classes, Ok I'll amend

Answer (score 2):

Just give an `id` or `class` to main parent `div` and first level of child `div`.

for example:

***HTML***

```
<div id="main">
 <div class="div1">

   <divA>
   </divA>

  <divB>
  </divB>

 </div>

 <div class="div2">
 </div>

</div>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('#main .div1').addClass('something');
```

### **[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/560/)**

**OR**

```
$('#main div:eq(0)').addClass('something');
```

### **[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/559/)**

Comment: Doesn't seems to work :  $('#main div:nth-child(1)').addClass("myclass"); works but adds classes to divA

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't edit the markup otherwise, you could run an `each()` on the elements and only apply the class the first time:

```
​$('div :nth-child(1)').each(function(i, el){
    if (i == 0) $(this).addClass('red-border');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
});
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f4sue/)